# Intellij and 64bit Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, ide

IntelliJ 13.1.4 Community on Win7 64bit.  The page [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) says that, once the 64-bit JDK is installed, then `idea64.exe` should use the registry to locate JDK. Indeed, I have a nice key in my registry with what look to be proper values:

[image: current reg]

I'd like to have `idea64.exe` use this since it means I have to do nothing. But, it tells me it cannot find the jvm and that I must install it.

So I set the `JDK_HOME` variable to point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`

Same problem.

So I set IDEA_JDK_64 to point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20` and that finally convince it to load!

Bug?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions, but no one help. Then a moved **tools.jar** from **"Idea_home"/jre/lib** to **"Idea_home"/lib** and **64-bit IDEA** properly launched. (also you may copy tools.jar from **"JDK"/lib** patch)